# MySQL query - how order by 2 rows in one table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using MySQL Server 5.x and I have a posts table that stores post data for a site. Sometimes a post can be a child post of a parent post, in which case the table records the post parent's ID number.

The table has an ID field ( bigint ), a post_parent field ( also bigint ), a title, and content.

Sample data may look like this

```
ID  post_parent  title    content
----------------------------------------------
1                test     testing post content
2                test2    more test content
3   1            test3    post 1 is my parent
4   2            test4    post 2 is my parent
5                tes5     test content post 5
6   2            test6    post 2 is my parent
```

So I want to query the table for X number of records, and order the results by post ID with children of that post grouped with the parent, where the result would look like this:

```
ID  post_parent  title    content
----------------------------------------------
1                test     testing post content
3   1            test3    page 1 is my parent
2                test2    more test content
4   2            test4    page 2 is my parent
6   2            test6    post 2 is my parent
5                test5    test content post 5
```

So based on the answers give apparently I can use something like this:

SELECT ID, post_parent, title, content
FROM myTable
ORDER BY COALESCE(post_parent, ID), ID

But, I need to add another twist here. Lets say there are 16000 records in the table in some sort of random order, meaning the second 100 records ( e.g. records 101 - 200 ) might all be post children, but I always want to return the results where parents of children are always returned with the children. So with the above query if I use "limit 100, 25" I wind up getting results that are only children with no parent. How can I avoid that and have the related parents always returned with the children colaesced properly?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, post_parent, title, content
FROM myTable
ORDER BY COALESCE(post_parent, ID), ID
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58fc6/1)

Comment: +1 Ha!  You beat me to it by about 19 seconds.  Exact same ORDER BY clause.  :)  I deleted mine.

Comment: Those work great in theory. However I need to add another twist here. Lets say there are 16000 records in the table in some sort of random order, meaning the second 100 records ( e.g. 101 - 200 ) might all be post children, but I always want to return the results where parents of children are always returned with the children. So if I use "limit 100, 25" I wind up getting results that are only children with no parent. How can I avoid that and have the related parents always returned with the children coalesced properly?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work using `CASE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN post_parent IS NOT NULL THEN post_parent ELSE Id END
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e03c/4)